# Saving a Django form to a csv file

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I have a Django form that is working fine. I'd like to save the data it submits to a CSV file. Is there a "best practice" way to do this?

I need to include blank fields in the CSV file where the user has not filled in a "required=False" field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the document [CSV File Reading and Writing](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) very helpful for your problem.